# ServiceController class not importing C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, using

Strange thing...theres no code this time but the using System.ServiceProcess; import gets a red line under the ServiceProcess portion of the import.

Does anyone know why? and is there an alternative to this class so that I can still start and stop windows services?

Comment: do you have System.ServiceProcess in references ?

Comment: it's a good idea always to provide a short, self contained exmaple that can illicit the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this assembly as a refrence: System.ServiceProcess.dll

In Visual Studio, right click References -> Add Reference -> Select System.ServiceProcess.dll -> OK

Comment: awesome! Glad I could help you out :)